# Fastest way to calculate a number of memory blocks

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a memory region, which is divided in blocks of predefined `BLOCKSIZE` size. Given a memory chunk, defined by its offset `OFFSET` in bytes and `SIZE` in bytes, how to efficiently calculate a number of blocks, containing this memory chunk?

For example, let's say the `BLOCKSIZE=8`. Then a memory chunk with `OFFSET=0` and `SIZE=16` will take 2 blocks, but a chunk with `OFFSET=4` and `SIZE=16` will take 3 blocks.

I can write a formula like this (using integer arithmetics in C):

```
numberOfBlocks = (OFFSET + SIZE - 1) / BLOCKSIZE - (OFFSET / BLOCKSIZE) + 1;
```

This calculation will take 2 divisions and 4 additions. Can we do better, provided that the `BLOCKSIZE` is a **power of 2** and `OFFSET >= 0` and `SIZE > 0`?

UPDATE: I uderstand that division can be replaced by shifting in this case.

Comment: Your formula does not agree with your requirements.  Consider the case when `OFFSET == 0`, `SIZE == 16`, and `BLOCKSIZE == 2`.  Your formula evaluates to `3` in that case, but you say the desired result is `2` (and that makes sense).

Comment: @JohnBollinger - you are right, thanks! I'll update it

Comment: One potential optimization is to insure that you don't use signed arithmetic by accident, thereby allowing the compiler can optimize the power-of-two case to a straight bit-shift since it doesn't have to worry about rounding towards zero (I'm assuming that negative values are impossible since the results would be incorrect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we do better, provided that the `BLOCKSIZE` is a **power of 2**?

I don't think so.  Your (corrected) formula is basically (index of the first block after the chunk) - (index of the first containing any part of the chunk). You could formulate it differently -- say, as the sum of a base number of blocks plus an adjustment for certain layouts that require one extra block -- but that actually increases the number of operations needed by a couple:

```
numberOfBlocks = (SIZE + BLOCKSIZE - 1) / BLOCKSIZE
        + ((SIZE % BLOCKSIZE) + (OFFSET % BLOCKSIZE)) / BLOCKSIZE;
```

I don't see any way around performing (at least) two integer divisions (or equivalent bit shifts), because any approach to the calculation requires computing *two* block counts.  These two computations cannot be combined, because each one requires a separate remainder truncation.

That `BLOCKSIZE` is a power of two may help you choose more efficient operations, but it does not help reduce the *number* of operations required.  However, you *could* reduce the number of operations slightly if you could rely on `SIZE` to be a multiple of `BLOCKSIZE`.  In that case, you could do this:

```
numberOfBlocks = SIZE / BLOCKSIZE + (OFFSET % BLOCKSIZE) ? 1 : 0;
```

Alternatively, if it would be sufficient to compute an *upper bound* on the number of blocks covered, then you could do this:

```
numberOfBlocksBound = SIZE / BLOCKSIZE + 2;
```

or slightly tighter in many cases, but more costly to compute:

```
numberOfBlocksBound = (SIZE + BLOCKSIZE - 1) / BLOCKSIZE + 1;
```